# How can I read xml data from internet in Android ListView?

Tags: android, xml, listview

How can i read the categories education and work in a android ListView? Now on clicking any category  its childs Google,IBM,etc. are shown in a new screen. How can it be implemented?

Comment: Have you tried to make a call on the same URL to retrieve XML?

Comment: i have succeded in reading xml.i do not know how to implement them in a list view seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow the following steps to get your work done

**Step-1** You need to parse the xml. see http://xmlpull.org/v1/src/java/samples/MyXmlPullApp.java

**Step-2** Create a bean class for Category. means all the category related data will be stored in that bean class

**Step-3** Create an arraylist of that bean class

**Step-4** Create a list view using that arraylist ( the list view will display only name of categories)

**Step-5** Implement on itemclik listener on the list view. get the position. retrieve the data pass to the intent call second activity

**Step-6** In the second activity create a listview and display the data whatever is passed by first activity

### NetworkBean

```
public class NetWorkBean {
    String name;
    int id;
    NetWorkBean(String name, int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNetWorkName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getNetWorkId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

### CategoryBean

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CategoryBean {
    String name;
    ArrayList<NetWorkBean> networkList;
    public CategoryBean(String name, ArrayList<NetWorkBean> networkList){
        this.name = name;
        this.networkList = networkList;
    }
    public String getNetWorkName(){
        return name;
    }
    public ArrayList<NetWorkBean> getNetWorkList(){
        return networkList;
    }


}
```

Comment: step 2 is currently my only problem.could you please gude on that.thanks for quick answer

Comment: hey how can i distinguish between the name in category and name in network while parsing the file

Answer (score 0):

you can see this

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser

After parsing the data set it to the list view.Then in the list onclick event implement

what you need.You can call an another activity and sending the corresponding address in a

bundle then retrieving that on the activity you can show in webview